# Which is the better way of calculating frame motion in a video?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, opticalflow

In order to find successive frame motion differences, I used absolute difference of the frames and then summing up all the pixels to quantify the amount motion. I have done that in OpenCV.

But I recently came to know about Horn and Schunk's Optical flow algorithm and the Macro-Block based motion compensation. OpenCV Library already has in built functions that can compute them. But I do not know how to quantify them. Are they better than the first approach ?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way optical flow is implemented in opencv is...

1. Initialy detect some points as good features to track(points of interest) in the frame(say FrameA) where the target to be tracked appears...some points may lie on the target some may lie on the background...
2. The points detected are stored in a vector array and passed to the Optical Flow function along with the FrameA and the FrameB...the later (FrameB) is the next frame where we intended to find the location of the points of interest...
3. When we get the position of the points of interest in FrameB we can estimate the displacement of the points of interest between FrameA and FrameB...

for your case...since you are doing frame motion calculation...use the background subtraction(frame differentiation..) as the technique to initiate the frame from where you can start finding points of interest...when the change goes above a threshold start acquiring points of interest...track them in the next consecutive frames and you can make a histogram of how many points of interest has under gone how much of displacement in the next frame...thats all I can think about now for quantifying frame motion...

Answer (score 1):

While I have little experience with the particular opencv implementations, I can tell you that optical flow typically does not attempt to quantify the amount of motion. You could define a metric on the output based on the length of the optical flow vectors (e.g. summing the block velocities), but this is a very different metric from the one you used. If this is useful to you depends on the application. For comparison, think about a grey object moving against a white background versus a black object moving against the white background. Your frame difference metric will perceive the black object as more motion, while the sum of block velocities metric will perceive this as roughly the same amount of motion.

Comment: I am working on Video Summarization. So, I guess measuring the amount of motion is important. Are the mentioned methods suitable for them ????

Answer (score 0):

Finally you should also consider the runtime of your method. The comutational complexity of an difference image is very low and could be estimated in a few millisecond. But you are not able to quatify the speed of your objects. E.g shaking camera could make problems. 
Less fast are Optical Flow based methods such as the pyramidal Lucas Kanade or the Horn Schunk method but you get for each pixel (dense methods such as Horn Schunk) or for a set of predefined pixels (sparse methods such as the pyramidal Lucas Kanade) a motion vector. So you are now able to distingiush between different moving objects or you just use the length of the computed motion vectors. But the runtime is about 200ms to 2 secound and depend on parameters, size of your frame and numbers of vectors to compute etc.